# Why is my session variable not changing?

Tags: php, html

Consider **File A**, **File B**, and **File X**, where both **File A** and **File B** include the *session* instance that is **File X**.

**File X** has a variable initialized like so:

```
$login_order_submitted = false;
```

**File A** has a branch of code (that I know is being executed) as follows:

```
$login_order_submitted = true;
header('Location: FileB.php');
exit();
```

**File B** has a conditional such that:

```
<?php 
     if ($login_order_submitted === true) {
?>
     <script>
          alert('Order Successfully Submitted!');
     </script>
<?php
     /* now reset the order submitted variable */
     $login_order_submitted = false;
     }
?>
```

Why is my code in **File B** falling through (the script/alert isn't running) when it's being set to `true` in the file (**File A**) that redirects to it?

The code for **File X** is below.

```
<?php
include('db_const.php');
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
// Selecting Database

session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=$connection->query("SELECT store_name, store_id FROM Store WHERE store_id='$user_check'");
$row = $ses_sql->fetch_assoc();
$login_user_name =$row['store_name'];
$login_user_ID = $row['store_id'];
$login_order_submitted = false;
if(!isset($login_user_name)){
    mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection
    header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

Comment: Variables are no saved between redirects, try using sessions or cookies.

Comment: @JamieBicknell I'm saving this variable in the session; I'll update my question to state this. Thank you.

Comment: Could you show us the code for the session?

Comment: @PaulH Done. Thank you.

Comment: You don't set  `$_SESSION['login_order_submitted']` or any session variables anywhere in that code.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I'm setting it elsewhere, sorry. I think I see my issue now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$_SESSION["login_order_submitted"]` instead of `$login_order_submitted`